# What parameter should I specify for Properties.Settings.Default.History so that it doesn't give an error with Null?

Tags: c#, wpf, nullreferenceexception

[I create the "History" parameter through the project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL1Pd.png)
and I'm trying to put a value in that parameter and save it:

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.History.Add("00:30");
 Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

But it's giving me an error:
System.NullReferenceException: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Fifteen.Properties.Settings.History.get вернул null.

what value do I need to enter in the parameter to make the error disappear?

**Additional information:**
I have a listbox called elapsedtimeitem, it should store all the results of a user's playthroughs. I also need to make sure that when I restart the application, these results (listbox) are not erased. That is, all Listbox items will remain. For this I want to use Properties.Settings.Default.History. I made the type for this property system collection specialized string collection.
I want that when I get a new user result (string) it will be written to Properties.Settings.Default.History. And from Properties.Settings.Default.History to write the value to elapsedtimeitem.
I made the following code:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.History.Add(elapsedtimeitem);
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

But I got an error. To be sure that it's not the variable I changed the code for the test to:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.History.Add("00:30");
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

And it gives an error with null. [But what value should I enter?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amm1o.png) It doesn't accept any string as a parameter, it doesn't accept an array either. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I don't understand what.

Comment: Well the History object is null so you can't call `.Add` on null. So there isn't really enough information here to be able to help you but you're going to need to figure out why the History object is null, what is the value for the Default settings object for example?

Comment: @justin.m.chase I've added additional information